# How can I get the OAuth authorization token for a user of IBM connection user using JAVA API? Also what is the validity of this token?

Tags: ibm-sbt

I need some help in finding the correct JAVA API required to fetch the OAuth authorization token for an IBM connections user.

Comment: Why do you need the token?  The token validity is determined by Connections and is configurable, so it is hard to know when the token is no longer valid up front.  With OAuth tokens you continue to use them until the Provider rejects them (I think the spec says it will respond with a 401 but could be wrong).  Then the OAuth dance needs to occur again so you can get a new token.

Comment: I need the token so that I can access the users account and do a post on his activity screen on his behalf using my application

Answer (score 0):

You create the request, then the flow generates the request to the C4.5 oauth, then you get the token back,  the token is stored in the credential store, or in the session.

After thinking about this... you are probably also looking for this... https://greenhouse.lotus.com/sbt/SBTPlayground.nsf/JavaSnippets.xsp#snippet=Authentication_OAuth2_Connections_ActivityStream_From_My_Network   it shows how to use oauth via the api.

same code, it's just wrapped the experience into the api.